# Is it OK for HR to retract a contract that has been signed by the candidate?

Tags: contracts

I am Indonesian job seeker who live in Malaysia with my parents. I got an offer from Recruitment Agency A to work in Malaysia. I passed the interview and signed the contract. to proceed the working permit, they asked me to go back to Indonesia to get the VDR visa with flight and visa fees under my expenses. once I arrived at jakarta, I got a call from Recruitment agency saying:

> "We’ve a terrible news,  the position offered to is redundant and there is no headcount for this role because of sudden pull back. Thus, the HR Team had to retract the offer"

As a consequences, I lost the offer, my long term visa and my flight cost at one time. I tried to get the explanation but still I don't understand the real case with all the HR terms:

What the meaning by redundant position?
What is the meaning of no headcount?
What is the meaning of sudden pull back?
Lastly, what is my right and the ethical sense behind this?

Comment: You'll need to discuss this with a lawyer - whether they can just cancel a signed contract (I'm assuming both parties signed, not just you?) depends on the content of that contract and the local lesiglation.

Comment: Sounds like you need legal advice here. We can't know for sure _why_ they did what they did.

Comment: The most likely reason is that they had an unexpected cut to their budget or  a hiring freeze (also generally to save money). Often the hiring officials were not aware of some decisions in the process of being made at higher levels in the company that will affect the hiring. So what happens is you hire someone. Two days later, the company says every group must reduce salary expenses by 20% or the project is cancelled. This happens all the time in business. So you rescind the offer because there is no longer money to pay for it.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

`What the meaning by redundant position?`
The company has financial difficulties and has no more money to keep the employees working on that position. They probably fired the existing employees and of course will not hire new ones.

`What is the meaning of no headcount?`
They probably don't need any employees working on that position anytime soon.

`what is the meaning of sudden pull back?`
The trouble came as a surprise for them.

`Lastly, what is my right and the ethical sense behind this?`
This possibly a legal one, but I would say there is nothing you can do and you probably will not get compensated for the flight tickets unfortunately.

Comment: Why the downvotes without comments? I answered his questions.

Comment: I did not downvote, but most of your answers look like pure assumptions without much proof, which would explain the downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the term explained. However, do the HR team initially confirm the headcount first before open a hiring? who is responsible for the headcount, the Recruitment agency or the client?

Comment: Well by my understanding all of your "Assumptions" of what is going on are wrong.  Maybe try to do a little research and back up your claims with some references.